# How to compare each array item to every other array item in Typescript-Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, for-loop, nested-loops, comparison-operators

I have an array with elements of a custom type I created and need logic to compare each one to every other one.
Found this code in js which would probably be good in ts but having some slight difficulties adapting it

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  for (int j = i+1; j < list.size(); j++) {
    // compare list.get(i) and list.get(j)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use forEach in Typescript.

```
const list: customType[] = [];

list.forEach(i => {
    list.forEach(j => {
        // compare between i and j
    });
});
```